# Blender Python select object within same group?

Tags: python, blender

I am using Python to create some shapes in blender.  I want to group these shapes together and use the following code to do that:

```
 import bpy

 bpy.ops.group.create(name= "NewGroup")
 bpy.ops.object.group_link(group="NewGroup")
 For i in range (1,3,1):
    tempobject = bpy.data.objects["Cube" + str(i)]
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active=tempobject
    bpy.ops.object.group_link(group="NewGroup")
```

When I try to select a group so I can join them to an active object:

```
 host_object = bpy.data.objects["Cube1"]
 bpy.context.scene.objects.active=host_object
 bpy.ops.object.select_same_group(group="NewGroup")

 bpy.ops.object.join() # all selected objects join to active object
```

it doesn't select any objects within the group.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having similar issues...

Comment: It works just fine with me. Did you write "For" and not "for" in the original code? That produced an error to me, maybe that's the problem... And is the second code in a different place? Are you sure you imported bpy? BTW, you should upload the error you get as well...

Comment: There is a much better place for Blender related questions: http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
bpy.context.scene.objects['objName'].select
```

before calling `select_same_group`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have an uppercase 'For' that should be 'for' as @Antoni4040 mentioned in the comments.

If this is not the problem, please paste the error.